TV series about hospital where supernatural things happen
I saw the first episode of this and part of another one in around the late 90's- maybe early 2000's. The hero was a doctor, one of a select few who were deemed worthy to work in this hospital. Over the first episode strange things happen in the building; a nurse says to the main character "the dead have power here", and the first episode ends with its villain, an older doctor, after being told to go to hell by the lead, says something like, "On my way," right before demonic looking arms attack him and take him somewhere else.
Another episode involved a paralyzed friend of the lead- I missed most of it but someone else told me said friend turned out to have been paralyzed because of neglect from the staff of the hospital this show was set in.

My immediate reaction to the question title was the Danish series Riget, but it has been so long since I watched it that I wouldn't be able to tell definitively. But I do think it took longer than the first episode for something overtly supernatural to happen.

This is All Souls (2001).

All Souls is an American paranormal hospital drama television series created by Stuart Gillard and Stephen Tolkin and inspired by Lars von Trier's miniseries The Kingdom. It originally aired for one season on UPN from April 17, 2001, to August 31, 2001. The series follows the medical staff of the haunted teaching hospital All Souls. While working as a medical intern, protagonist Dr. Mitchell Grace (Grayson McCouch) encounters various spirits, and discovers that the doctors are running unethical experiments on their patients.

At around 35 minutes into the first episode, "Pilot," Nurse Glory St. Claire tells the protagonist, Dr. Mitchell Grace, that "the dead have power here."
At around 40 minutes into the episode, Grace tells the antagonist, Dr. Ryman Kreeger, to "go to hell" and Kreeger responds "on my way." Several ghosts then appear behind Kreeger and drag him through a portal.
The second episode, "Spineless," involves a paralysed friend of Grace's named Patrick Fortado.

When Mitchell's friend, Patrick Fortado, is left paralyzed after being hit by a car, Mitchell's colleague, Dr. Stefani Volette, agrees to treat him, but a price must be paid for her special treatment to work.





I must admit to being a bit disappointed that this one wasn't Garth Marenghi's Darkplace! Still, well done on the rapid answer.
